# Proof that field of constants is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $d$ be $k$-derivation of $L=k(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ (field of rational functions over field k) defined by $d(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$. Then $L^d=k$.

Book says it's easy to prove it but i dont have any idea.

Comment: What does general element in $L$ look like?

Comment: $\frac{Q(x_1,x_2\dots)}{P(x_1,x_2\dots)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials with respect to $x_1,x_2 \dots$ over field $k$

Comment: Where $L^d$ is...?

Comment: $L^d=\{x\in L : d(x)=0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary for the characteristic of $k$ to be zero, for if $\mathrm{char}(k)=p$ then $d(x_1^p)=0$.

So lets assume $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ and $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in L\backslash k$ (by definition: $L=\cup_n k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$). So $n\geq 1$ and we can assume further that $f\not\in k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$. Then we have:
$$d(f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}d(x_1)+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}d(x_n) \\ = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}x_2+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}x_{n+1}. $$

But $f$ is a non-constant element of $(k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))(x_n)$ so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\neq 0,$ (here we use $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$) and so $d(f) = A + Bx_{n+1}$ for $A,B\in k(x_1,\dots,x_n), B\neq 0.$ So $d(f)$ is a nonzero element of $(k(x_1,\dots,x_n))(x_{n+1}) = k(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})$.

Comment: Thanks, but what do u denote by $(k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))(x_n)$ ? Field extension generated by $x_n$?

Comment: Yes, In fact $(k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))(x_n)$ is the same as $k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, but I used this to clarify what I mean by "constants", and I used the simple fact that every non-constant element of $K(x)$ ( $K$ a field with characteristic zero) has nonzero derivative.

Comment: Why the second part is true? " I used the simple fact that every non-constant element of .."? thanks

Comment: You can  write down explicitly the derivative of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ and show the derivative decreases the degree exactly by one if the degree is not equal to zero. (degree = degree of numerator minus degree of denominator)